# angular 4 - How to paginate data from database?

Tags: angular

The data from database are already display, but no pagination yet,

**in my component**

```
this._membersService.getMembers().subscribe(data => {this.members = data});
```

**in my service**

```
getMembers() {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost/membership/main/getUsers')
    .map(response => response.json() );
}
```

Is pagination difficult in angular 4? How can I paginate the data?

thanks :)

Comment: Angular4 itself does not provide pagination. You can pick a table plugin of your choice that supports pagination.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new Angular Material component called [Paginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api). The API provides you PageIndex, PageSize and other useful properties to handle pagination. Regarding server-side -as you haven't mentioned the technology you're using- I can only say you have to filter the records you return basing on the info you get from the Paginator.

Answer (score 0):

On pressing the pagination buttons, make new db calls with parameters, for example: `this._membersService.getMembers(from, to)` where from and to variables are ID-s for the DB select.

Or use a 3d party [component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable-pagination)